# Mixing JavaScript and Razor syntax

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I was looking for how to mix razor and JavaScript together. I found something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var currentUser = null;
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
    <text>
        currentUser = '@User.Identity.Name';
    </text>
}
</script>
```

Why is the variable called `currentUser` surrounded with `<text></text>` tag? What is the meaning of `<text>` tag? If we omit that text tag then any error occur?

Comment: have a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17419111/mixing-razor-syntax-with-javascript-in-views/17419419#17419419

Comment: This is not a real question. _"What happens if..."_. **Try it**. You have the code in front of you, you can test it. StackOverflow isn't a crowdsourcing compiler. At the least, you can show you are willing to learn and trying to understand the problem. You could have done a search, where you would have found [how to use text tag in MVC 3 razor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969065/how-to-use-text-tag-in-mvc-3-razor).

Comment: if i write the code like this way then error occur ? @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) { currentUser = '@User.Identity.Name'; }

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is how razor works. It uses brackets and tags begin/end to differenciate c# code from generated HTML

When you open a bracket, it it considered code until :

- a corresponding closing bracket is encounterd
- a tag is opened.

Then , opened tag will be considered html until a@ or correspoding closing tag is encountered.
Sometimes, you want to switch from c# to HTML (or js) but you don't want to add a tag... then special tag  id there for you. It is not rendered, just here to tell razor to switch rom C# to generated output

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the `<text>…</text>` tags is to solve the issue of ambiguities that arise as a result of your mixing two languages together that are semantically identical in many cases.

If you were to specify dynamic java script logic within the Razor syntax's C# if statements, and you had java script if statements in those blocks, how would it differentiate the context between the two?

The problem is: it can't; odds are, programmers can't either.  The `<text>…</text>` tag is a special Razor block (inside C# blocks only) style escape that says: this is definitely (probably) not C# code that is in this block.

Things get a bit dicey when you realize you can then add *another* escape inside the `<text>…</text>` block.  Like anything though you would use it with caution.  If you're having a lot of trouble mixing the two and can't figure out where to add your text blocks, odds are you shouldn't be using it (in production) until you understand it better.