# Why Does my Javascript Function Run on Load

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this code on my Create view.

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
        <!--Ingredients-->
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ingredients, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })<br />
        <textarea class="form-control" id="ingredients" rows="20" onsubmit="PopulateIngredients()"></textarea>
    </div>


    <script>
        function PopulateIngredients()
        {
            var ingredientArray = document.getElementById('ingredients').val().split('/n');
            if (ingredientArray.length !=0)
            {
                for (i = 0; i < ingredientArray.length; i++)
                {
                    @(Model.Ingredients).Add(ingredientArray[i]);
                }

            }

        }
    </script>
```

When the page is loading I get an error in the script saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." at this line;

```
    @(Model.Ingredients).Add(ingredientArray[i]);
```

Two problems exist. One is that I should be seeing the model.Ingredients IEnumerable object. Two is that his script shouldn't run until the submit button is clicked.

What am I doing wrong? I have to use a text area for input so I have to split it and add it to the ingredient list before it is posted back to the controller where it is handled as a list of ingredient objects. I did not include the classes for brevity.

Comment: What is that serverside markup (with the `@`), ASP? Please tag your question with it.

Comment: That error message is a .NET error, and the code is still parsed at runtime, even if the javascript function isn't called.

Comment: And it looks like a dupe of this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779091/what-does-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-mean

Comment: isn't this a problem of javascript executing before the DOM is loaded ?..

Comment: Are you passing a model to this view? It looks like @Model == null. And you can't mix JavaScript client-side code with the server-side Razor code (in this way). It'll not work.

Comment: Yes I am passing the model. I could have included the entire cshtml but I did not because I didn't think it was necessary. I just included the lines that are causing a problem.

Comment: You don't pass the model in cshtml, but in the server-side C# code. Could you please show your controller code and the model code?

Answer (score 1):

```
@(Model.Ingredients).Add(ingredientArray[i]);
```

is a server side script which will be executed when the view is prepared. So this line will be executed when you load the page. And that is why you  are getting `null reference` error, because `Model.Ingredients` is not yet initialized.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to handle this problem then? I am going to have to do something like this for a few more fields so I need to understand the problems.

Comment: You can use JSON string to post these values. First add these elements to an javascript array (say myArray), then create an JSON object some thing like this (var obj = {Ingredients : myArray}). then create the data to be send (data = JSON.stringify(obj)), then post this data using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like @Model == null. You have to pass the model instance to the view:

`return View(model);`

And you can't mix the JavaScript client-side code with the server-side Razor code (in the way you do it). It'll not work.

This might be helpful:
[Mix Razor and Javascript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614941/mix-razor-and-javascript-code) or 
[Mixing JavaScript and Razor syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989683/mixing-javascript-and-razor-syntax)

Comment: I read the two references. No good. I just need a way to add items to the list in this javascript function. Unless there is a better way to post the list during the save.

Comment: @ScottinTexas You can do this in many ways, but I can't help you until you post the code of the controller and the model. I need to know what your data types are and how you want to interpret the values sent to the controller.