# javascript location href not working on jquery ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following issue: I make a jQuery ajax post and, on success, I need to change the location of the browser to an Index view.
This is the javascript:

```
$.post(CreateReleaseNotificationURL, Notifications_Form.serialize(), function (response) {
            if (response.indexOf("Error") == 0) {
                $("#NewNotification_CreateStatus").html(response);
            }
            else {
                window.location.assign('@Url.Action("Index")');
                //window.location = window.location;                   
            }              
        })
        .fail(function () {                
            $("#NewNotification_CreateStatus").html("An error has occured.<br /> Please contact the system administrator<br /> if the problem persists.");
        });
```

However, nothing happens !! What am I missing ?

PS: I also tried using location.href, to no avail.

Comment: Is the control coming inside your conditional checks ?

Comment: Did u tried like window.location.href = "/app/Controller/Method_name" ?

Comment: @harsha, what control are you talking about ?

Comment: @vinothini, I don't want to use magic strings, I only want to use Url helper and such, since in production the magic string will most likely not work

Comment: If this is inside a .js file it won't work as it's not rendered. Otherwise, two debug phases. First check the HTML source to see what's `@Url.Action("Index")` been rendered to, second phase of debug is making sure you reached that line at all by adding `alert("...");`

Comment: javascript control. Are you sure that the result is a success ?

Comment: Try `window.location.reload();`

Comment: Thank all, it works fine, i just designed badly my javascript: i had two possible cases and only updated the location of the browser for one of them. Sorry to have waisted your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this:

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "ControllerName")';
```

Answer (score 0):

As posted here ([Mixing razor syntax with Javascript in views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17419111/mixing-razor-syntax-with-javascript-in-views)), it should be:

Inside the View file:

```
<input type="button" value="Resume" id="myButton" data-url='@Url.Action("Index")' />
```

Inside the javascript file (adapt it for your need):

```
$(function() {
    $('#myButton').click(function() {
        window.location.href = $(this).data('url');
    });
});
```